# Flask Socketio - limit emits per client

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to make a chat app but am worried that the client will be able to overload the server. I am using the following code for the client to send messages:

```
        var form = $( document.getElementById( "msg" ) ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
            message : user_input,
            room: room_new
          } )
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
```

The problem is the client can control when messages are sent and use setInterval() to overload the server. Does flask socket-io take care of this automatically, or is there some code I need to use for precaution?

Comment: Flask-SocketIO does not rate limit clients, so this is something you need to implement on your own application. The idea is that if you see events from a client passing some threshold you can disconnect the client to prevent it from flooding the server.

Comment: @Miguel - Thank you for the quick reply. Is there some sort of rate limiting auto implemented in Flask, or do I need to store connections in a database to solve this problem?

Comment: There are extensions for Flask that implement rate limiting (see https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but those are for Flask routes, they will not work for Socket.IO events.